# Accessing Appointments in Outlook without ActiveX

Tags: outlook, office365, activex, outlook-web-app

I'm currently working on a project where I'm sending and updating Appointsments. I would like to do this without the use of ActiveX since I don't want to be limited to IE. I've been googeling for quite some time now, but I couldn't find anything that helped, so here's my question. Is there any way I can access or update appointments without the use of ActiveX.
We also have access to the OutlookWebApp, so maybe there's an interface there. Would be great if someone had an idea. Thanks in advance and

Greetings Chris

Comment: Can you clarify what ActiveX and/or a browser have to do with interacting with Outlook for your intended solution?  Is this a web or desktop application?  Or an Outlook client or web add-in?  For Office 365 or Exchange accounts or any kind of email account (POP, IMAP)?

Comment: At the moment I'm communication with the Outlook desktop application via ActiveX to get Meeting Info and Send Invitations and such. But I'm searching for an alternative way to retrieve that data without the use of ActiveX. It's not necessary that this information is retrieved from the desktop application. If there is a way to acces the data on the exchange server directly or through some sort of interface to the OutlookWebApp this would also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Exchange Web Services (web or desktop app) or the EWS Managed API (desktop app only) to access data in Exchange Mailboxes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162981.aspx.

If you are working with Office 365 mailboxes you can use the Outlook REST or Microsoft Graph APIs: https://dev.outlook.com/

If your solution requires a UI in Outlook Online (OWA) then you can access contextual data (i.e. the current email or appointment) with an Outlook Add-in (you can use EWS requests from it as well): https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/

Comment: I found some info about the Outlook REST API. Maybe im interpreting it wrong, but I always thought this was to work inside of the Web App. Not accessing Exchange Data from another Origin/Website. Is there a possibility to use this CrossOrigin?

Comment: You can use it in a native/desktop app, web add-ins as well as a web or mobile app.  You will have to register your app in order for Office 365 users to grant permissions to your app.  However, you can't use the REST APIs for on-prem Exchange. You'd have to use EWS for that.

Comment: OK. That helps. Thanks